# Memoryleak with QListWidget addItem() + setItemWidget()

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt5

When I press a key there shall be a query to an engine. The results get put into a `QListWidget` by adding an item and setting the widget. Somehow this causes a massive memory overflow and even crashed my machine. But I dont get the error. Does `clear()` not delete the items passed to the `QListWidget` and the widgets set by `setItemWidget()`. I even tried to delete them on my own (comment), but still got a memoryleak. The error is in the `if (!results.empty())`-block, I guess, since commenting it out plugs the memoryleak.

```
void Widget::onTextEdited(const QString & text)
{
    //  QListWidgetItem * takenItem;
    //  while (takenItem = _results->takeItem(0)){
    //      delete _results->itemWidget(takenItem);
    //      delete takenItem;
    //  }
    _results->clear();  _results->hide();

    if (!text.isEmpty())
    {
        const std::vector<const Items::AbstractItem *> results = _engine.request(text);
        if (!results.empty())
        {
            for (auto i : results){
                QListWidgetItem *lwi = new QListWidgetItem;
                _results->addItem(lwi);
                ListItemWidget *w = new ListItemWidget;
                w->setName(i->name());
                w->setTooltip(i->path());
                _results->setItemWidget(lwi, w);
            }
            _results->setFixedHeight(std::min(5,_results->count()) * 48); // TODO
            _results->show();
        }
    }
    this->adjustSize();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use a memory leak detection tool instead of guessing around :)

**UPDATE**: clear() only deletes items but does not delete the widgets belonging to it. The widgets will be deleted if the QListWidget is deleted.

<s>clear() does delete items and widgets belonging to it. And you mentioned that commenting out **if(!results.empty())** solved the problem. I don't see any problem in the setItemWidget part. So I think the problem lies somewhere else, maybe `ListItemWidget`. How about you try replacing `ListItemWidget` with `QLabel` and see what happens. Eg:</s>

```
QListWidgetItem *lwi = new QListWidgetItem;
_results->addItem(lwi);
//ListItemWidget *w = new ListItemWidget;
//w->setName(i->name());
//w->setTooltip(i->path());
QLabel *w = new QLabel;
w->setText("Hello");
_results->setItemWidget(lwi, w);
```

Comment: I just tried it. The memoryleak persists. Valgrind tells me that there is no error.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, what about commenting the QLabel and setItemWidget part, leaving only the first two lines (new QListWidgetItem and addItem). And what's the thing that tells you that there's a memory leak? The program crashes?

Comment: Found it out: clear() does not delete the widgets. It just removes the widgets. Thanks for your help,

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, my bad! I thought clear() does delete widgets cause w has a parent after calling setItemWidget(). Obviously listWidget will only delete widgets after it is deleted itself. So in your case widgets will keep taking memory until listWidget is deleted.